# koowa: How to stop Strict Standards errors

Tags: joomla

My JOOMLA 2.5.19 site (orcv.org.au) has developed error reporting overnight on a number of "strict standards" errors in a koowa library.
The hosting site has recently upgraded PHP to 5.4.26

I do not know how to upgrade the library, fix the coding error myself, find which part of joomla uses koowa or disable the error reporting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question has been asked countless times on Stackoverflow. Set your error reporting in the Global Configuration to Default or Simple, else edit your *php.ini* (if you have access to it) accordingly

Comment: Did you check to see if there is an update available for Koowa?  A lot  of strict errors are pretty easy to fix so if there are just a few it's something you could do but if it is pervasive (such as if static declarations were left out of lots and lots of methods) then it's a big project.